# how to clear all css before Nested bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

something is interfering with my grid . everything should be working. I tested it as a single grid in another html file and it is as expected.

```
<div id="bookpanel" class="container-fluid"  style="background-color:purple;" >
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-12 col-sm-12 mb-4" style="background-color:grey;" >
                    ttt
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4" id="bookfigure"   style="background-color:black;"   >
                        <img src = "/images1/aaa" class="img-responsive" title="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 " id="booktags"  style="background-color:grey;" >      
                        <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-10"  style="background-color:blue;" >
                                        aaaa
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-2"  style="background-color:yellow;" >
                                        bbbb
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12" style="background-color:red;" >
                                        tags:
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12" id="tagsdiv"  style="background-color:green;"  >
                                       ccc
                                    </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-4" >
                    Views: 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-4">
                    <a href="" ><img src="/images/gifs/Download-Button.gif" style="width:100%;height:50px" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-4">
                    <a href="" ><span id="report">report</span></a>
                </div>
    </div>
```

but it does not in a larger file and it shows like this image :
the same behavior in the small screen of a mobile phone.

[image]

the 3  (red,green,blue) columns should be inside the grey box

Comment: Hard to help you without any CSS but it looks like you have negative margins affecting your boxes.

Comment: yes thanks . I fixed it. should I delete this question?